# Can light falling out of socket, how to resolve issue?

Tags: light-fixture

This light is starting to fall out of its socket. What can be done to alleviate the issue? Are there spacers that can be put into the sides or does this have to be addressed in the attic above the light?

[image]

Comment: If you take the bulb out, let the entire ring down, then take a pic of both the ring and the can it's in, then we can tell you how it's supposed to be attached, (Could be springs, friction, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Usually the trim ring fits up into the can with spring tension from bent metal fingers that grip the inside of the can.

If you remove it and pry the fingers out slightly it should re-insert tighter and hold up tight against the ceiling.

Stay safe!